# background-image in css not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my background in CSS.

This is my code:

```css
body{
    background: url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If I delete -image the background works correctly but if I put -image and delete fixed it works correctly.

Can someone help me?

Comment: use `background-attachment: fixed;` instead of `fixed`

Comment: Thanks you, now is working!

Comment: so mark my answer

Comment: hopefully this might come in handy: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) is shorthand so you can include multiple background properties.  [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) only allows you to state the url for the background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background: #ffff url(image) no-repeat top left` is actually short for

```
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url(image);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top left;
```

Setting the `background-size` property to `cover` makes `background-repeat` obsolete.
If you set `background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg")`, it makes `no-repeat` obsolete. The `fixed` does actually nothing there.

As Zuber suggested, just write the long hand properties.

```
body {
  background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change some `CSS`

```
body{
    background: url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat ;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `background-attachment: fixed;` instead of `fixed`

```css
body  {
    background-image: url("https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>The background-image is fixed. Try to scroll down the page.</p>
<p>If you do not see any scrollbars, try to resize the browser window.</p>
```

Comment: this is my answer

Comment: Why did you do this?

Comment: for example.... i did it before i see he told me it helped him so i think now it helps him so it fair that vote for me ... tell me if i worng!!

Comment: This `background: url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed;` is equal `background: url("../img/bg.jpg") ;background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;` .what is changed?

Comment: did you try????????\

Comment: ` background: url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat fixed;`  Works well for me. downvote to question because, it is'nt clear.

Comment: you right... :|

Answer (score 0):

The property `background-image` doesn't take multiple value, it only takes `url("../img/bg.jpg")` as value. If you want to assign multiple value you should assign it to `background` property. For separating all the background properties, you can try this code.

```
body {
    background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```